# Need to change the name of the app on the main screen in Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

Hi guys there is something wrong with my code because instead of showing me the name of the app where it should, It is simply showing @string/app_name .
This is my code in AndroidManifest.xml :`

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:debuggable="true"  >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

```
</resources>

<string name="app_name">OMGAndroid</string>
<string name="textview">Bada Aaya</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="button">Update the TextView</string>
```

Comment: It is also showing a lot of errors in my string.xml file

Comment: put your string.xml @ArjavGarg

Comment: So, your `strings.xml` starts with a closing (and never opened) tag... `</resources>` - Ask yourself **WHY** doesn't it work.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein Thanks for the correction bro..

Answer (score 1):

You must put the `<string>` between `<resources>` tags

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">OMGAndroid</string>
    <string name="textview">Bada Aaya</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="button">Update the TextView</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: Now I'd upvote a second time, but I'm not given the ability to... ;)

Comment: If you're feeling so generous how about awarding me a bounty or something ;)

Comment: Then I could buy you a beer :D

Answer (score 0):

Check the name of the resources xml you have used. It should be "strings.xml".
Also, the resources tag should be used something like this -

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">OMGAndroid</string>
    <string name="textview">Bada Aaya</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="button">Update the TextView</string>
</resources>
```